# Finding a type-safe replacement for int argument to a C++ function representing one or more operations

Tags: c++, enums, type-safety

### Question Summary

Is there a type-safe replacement of arguments to functions that take
an `int` but that interpret the value as a set of bitwise values that
represent mutually-exclusive operations, but that prevents callers
from using magic numbers to represent those operations? This needs
to work with GCC 4.8.5, without upgrading.

### Detailed Question

I have inherited an old C-style C++ function that accepts an `int`
argument that indicates some operations to do. These operations are
currently passed to the function as `0x1 | 0x2`, and are spread out
all over the code base. This is, in my opinion, a pretty
unmaintainable situation: It requires callers to use magic numbers,
and as such, forces the developers to read the entire function
implementation just to understand the operations being requested.

Thus, I seek to change the interface to use names that clearly
indicate what is being requested of the function to perform, while
still maintaining most of the existing function interface other than
the change of the particular argument's type. I cannot, in the
short-term, refactor the function to use a proper polymorphic approach
where operations are represented as separate classes, as the use of
these magic numbers has become too widespread do to that in one single
refactoring operation. I desire to require that any additional
operations added to the function then require some central type to be
changed to clearly indicate all of the valid named combinations of
operations that function must do, versus allowing impatient developers
the luxury of hacking in yet another value, e.g., `0x6`, and changing
the internals of the function to check for that value using ever
increasing unmaintainable conditional logic. In my mockup below of
where I've defined the `SomeEnum` type, and showed how it is still
hackable (see `SCENARIO_4`). It is that hacking I wish to enlist the
compiler to prevent.

The best I have been able to come up with is the `SomeEnumImposter`
class below. This is non-ideal from a caller point of view, since it
is cumbersome to have to type expressions of the form:

```
SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter().C().D());
```

Ideally, I would be able to do this:

```
SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(EIx(C, D));
```

where `EIx` would be some type of construct that would expand into
that cumbersome expression above. But to do that, I'd have to resort
to using variadic macros which are GCC-specific, or to avoid that, I'd
have to manually expand out macros of the form:

```
#define EI1(x1) SomeEnumImposter().x1()
#define EI2(x1, x2) SomeEnumImposter().x1().x2()
#define EI3(x1, x2, x3) SomeEnumImposter().x1().x2().x3()
#define EI4(x1, x2, x3, x4) SomeEnumImposter().x1().x2().x3().x4()
// etc.
```

Frankly, this `SomeEnumImposter` class is quite a lot of code just to
guard against impatient developers.  Is there a simpler way that works
with this specific compiler (no compiler upgrades are allowed; see the
gcc version being dumped out below).

### Update #1

Added `CLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS` as an attempted at using `struct Options` that was mentioned in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309629/257924

That is getting closer, but the syntax is still RSI-producing, as it takes up at most three lines just to say "C or D" in the call:

```
Options options;
options.C = true;
options.D = true;
SomeOptionsUsingFunction(options);
```

What I really need is something that is a mostly drop-in replacement for passing in hardcoded values into the existing function.

### Update #2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309629/257924 also mentions `myFunction` as a template function, but I cannot use that option since it means exposing the entire original function I am changing into a header, and it is too large to do that.

### Mockup

`main.cpp` contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum SomeEnum {
  E_INVALID = 0,
  E_A = 1,
  E_B = 1 << 1,
  E_C = 1 << 2,
  E_D = 1 << 3,
};

void SomeEnumUsingFunction(SomeEnum se)
{
  if (se & (E_C | E_D)) {
    printf("Has: C or D\n");
  }
}

void ExperimentWithSomeEnum()
{
  {
    printf("Attempting A\n");
    SomeEnum se(E_A);
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C\n");
    SomeEnum se(E_C);
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting D\n");
    SomeEnum se(E_D);
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C | D\n");

#ifdef SCENARIO_1
    // This next line below is simple, but gcc errors out with:
    //
    //   error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘SomeEnum’ [-fpermissive]
    //
    // GCC == c++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-3)
    SomeEnum se(E_A | E_D);
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
#endif

#ifdef SCENARIO_2
    SomeEnum se(static_cast<SomeEnum>(E_A | E_D));
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
#endif

#ifdef SCENARIO_3
    // This is a little better but still stinks as the caller _has_ to wrap the
    // value around "SomeEnum(...)" which is annoying.
    SomeEnum se(SomeEnum(E_A | E_D));
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
#endif

#ifdef SCENARIO_4
    // OOOPS: Completely defeated!! Some lazy programmer can hack in "1 << 8"
    // and change SomeEnumUsingFunction without having to change the header that
    // defines SomeEnum. I want to syntactically prevent them from being lazy
    // and hacking around the type system to avoid recompiling "the world" that
    // will necessarily occur when the header is changed.
    SomeEnum se(SomeEnum(E_A | E_D | (1 << 8)));
    SomeEnumUsingFunction(se);
#endif

  }
}

class SomeEnumImposter
{
public:
  SomeEnumImposter() : _additions(E_INVALID) {}
  // Using default copy constructor.
  // Using default operator=().

#define define_getter_and_setter(X)             \
  SomeEnumImposter & X()                        \
  {                                             \
    _additions = SomeEnum(_additions | E_##X);  \
    return *this;                               \
  }                                             \
  bool has##X()                                 \
  {                                             \
    return _additions & E_##X;                  \
  }

  define_getter_and_setter(A);
  define_getter_and_setter(B);
  define_getter_and_setter(C);
  define_getter_and_setter(D);

private:
  SomeEnum _additions;
};

void SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter se)
{
  if ( se.hasC() || se.hasD() ) {
    printf("Has: C or D\n");
  }
}

void ExperimentWithSomeEnumImposter()
{
  // Poor-mans assert():
  if ( ! (sizeof(SomeEnum) == sizeof(SomeEnumImposter)) ) {
    printf("%s:%d: ASSERTION FAILED: sizeof(SomeEnum) == sizeof(SomeEnumImposter)\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    return;
  }

  {
    printf("Attempting A\n");
    SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter().A());
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C\n");
    SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter().C());
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting D\n");
    SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter().D());
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C | D\n");
    SomeEnumImposterUsingFunction(SomeEnumImposter().C().D());
  }
}

struct Options {
  Options() : A(false), B(false), C(false), D(false) {}
  bool A;
  bool B;
  bool C;
  bool D;
};

void SomeOptionsUsingFunction(Options option_)
{
  if ( option_.C || option_.D ) {
    printf("Has: C or D\n");
  }
}

void ExperimentWithClassWithBoolDatamembers()
{
  {
    printf("Attempting A\n");
    Options options;
    options.A = true;
    SomeOptionsUsingFunction(options);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C\n");
    Options options;
    options.C = true;
    SomeOptionsUsingFunction(options);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting D\n");
    Options options;
    options.D = true;
    SomeOptionsUsingFunction(options);
  }
  {
    printf("Attempting C | D\n");
    Options options;
    options.C = true;
    options.D = true;
    SomeOptionsUsingFunction(options);
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *const envp[])
{
#ifdef PLAIN_ENUM
  ExperimentWithSomeEnum();
#endif
#ifdef ENUM_IMPOSTER
  ExperimentWithSomeEnumImposter();
#endif
#ifdef CLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS
  ExperimentWithClassWithBoolDatamembers();
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

`compare.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

compile_and_run () {
  local define_a_macro="$1"
  rm -f main.o
  /usr/bin/g++  -MD -DDEBUG -g $define_a_macro -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0  -fPIC  -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type   main.cpp -c -o main.o
  /usr/bin/g++  -MD -DDEBUG -g $define_a_macro -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0  -fPIC  -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type   main.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++  -o main.exe
  ./main.exe
}

echo
/usr/bin/g++ --version

set -e

echo
echo "PLAIN_ENUM:"
(
  set -x -e
  compile_and_run -DPLAIN_ENUM
)

echo
echo "ENUM_IMPOSTER:"
(
  set -x -e
  compile_and_run -DENUM_IMPOSTER
)

echo
echo "CLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS:"
(
  set -x -e
  compile_and_run -DCLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS
)
```

Running `./compare.sh` produces this output:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


PLAIN_ENUM:
+ compile_and_run -DPLAIN_ENUM
+ local define_a_macro=-DPLAIN_ENUM
+ rm -f main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DPLAIN_ENUM -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.cpp -c -o main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DPLAIN_ENUM -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++ -o main.exe
+ ./main.exe
Attempting A
Attempting C
Has: C or D
Attempting D
Has: C or D
Attempting C | D

ENUM_IMPOSTER:
+ compile_and_run -DENUM_IMPOSTER
+ local define_a_macro=-DENUM_IMPOSTER
+ rm -f main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DENUM_IMPOSTER -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.cpp -c -o main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DENUM_IMPOSTER -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++ -o main.exe
+ ./main.exe
Attempting A
Attempting C
Has: C or D
Attempting D
Has: C or D
Attempting C | D
Has: C or D

CLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS:
+ compile_and_run -DCLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS
+ local define_a_macro=-DCLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS
+ rm -f main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DCLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.cpp -c -o main.o
+ /usr/bin/g++ -MD -DDEBUG -g -DCLASS_WITH_BOOL_DATAMEMBERS -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type main.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++ -o main.exe
+ ./main.exe
Attempting A
Attempting C
Has: C or D
Attempting D
Has: C or D
Attempting C | D
Has: C or D
```

Comment: Can you use C++11?  I think gcc 4.8.5 has full support, and taht'd let you use parameter packs.

Comment: Are you looking for [enum class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)?

Comment: @StephenNewell Unfortunately no I cannot use Cxx11 yet as this is not the only compiler I have to code against at the moment. When we ditch support for the old compilers, then the ...

Comment: @JesperJuhl ... `enum class` that Jesper mentioned becomes an attractive option.

Comment: "proper polymorphic approach" no, not really. It's totally uncalled for. You want a bitset-like type with names for individual bits. A simple enum like `Option0=1<<0, Option1=1<<1, Option2=1<<2...` could be sufficient: if not, encapsulate in a class if your own and overload bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1):

### Options Class

Create an options struct/class like this and use as input to the function

```
struct Options {
    bool option1;
    bool option2;
    bool option3;
};
```

If you are concerned about padding you can use a c++ bitfield (although this risks others 'abusing' it).

### Option Class Detailed Use (after clarification)

To use as one liner/in-line you may use aggregate initialization (requires c++11, but enabled by default):

```
struct Options {
    bool option1;
    bool option2;
    bool option3;
};

void myFunc(Options options) {
}

void test() {
    myFunc(Options{ false, false, true });//OK
    myFunc({ false, false, true });//also OK
}
```

If not, or you prefer that aggregate initialization should not be used, then you may just write a normal constructor that takes in all the options (this has the added flexibility of be able to provide some default values).

```
struct Options {
    Options(bool option_1 = true, bool option_2 = false);
    //...
};

myFunc(Options( false ));//using constructor
```

If you have a lot of bools it might be a good idea to name the actual options in some way, for example using enums:

```
struct Options {
    enum OptionA {
        off = false,
        on = true,
    };
    enum OptionB {
        do1,
        do2,
        do3
    };

    OptionA optionA;
    OptionB optionB;
    bool optionC;
};
```

### Template Policy (like) based design

Change the function to take one or more template parameter and provide different options. I think this is the solution you are aiming at.
Example:

```
struct Options {
    bool option1;
    bool option2;
    bool option3;
};


struct OptionA1 {
};

struct OptionA2 {
};

struct OptionSetA12 : public OptionA1, public OptionA2 {
};

OptionA1 optionSetA1;
OptionA2 optionSetA2;
OptionSetA12 optionSetA12;


struct OptionB1 {
};

struct OptionB2 {
};

OptionB1 optionB1;
OptionB2 optionB2;

template<class OptionA_T, class OptionB_T>
void myFunction(OptionA_T optionA_t, OptionB_T optionB_t, int someInput) {
    if (boost::is_convertible<Option_T, Option1>::value) {
        //do whatever option 1
    }
}

//specialized:
template<class OptionB_T>
void myFunction(OptionSetA12 optionSetA12, OptionB_T optionB_t, int someInput) {
    //specialized version for OptionSetA12, still has OptionB_T as parameter
}

void test() {
    myFunction(optionSetA12, optionB2, 0);
}
```

As you can see, going this way gives you a lot flexibility, without risking abuse and with very little downside. Over time you may be able move away from the `is_convertible` conditional and put code into the policy classes themselves. See for example  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Comment: The `struct Options` approach seems closest to what I'm after. I've updated my original post with Update #1 and Update #2 as responses to this since I'm disallowed from adding such detail in a comment in SO.  If there is a shorter way to use `struct Options`, all on one line, then we have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer, just a status of what where I left this:

I ended up just going with:

```
const unsigned int XXX = 1;
const unsigned int YYY = 1 << 1;
const unsigned int ZZZ = 1 << 2;
```

etc.  The main reason is that I found in practice that the issue with "SCENARIO_3" was just too burdensome to ask developers to cast bitwise-OR'ed combinations of the above to an enum type each time the resulting integer value was fed to the function that uses it.

What I've ended up with was this compromise:

```
void that_function(int check);
...
that_function(YYY | ZZZ);
```

At least with the above compromise, they aren't hardcoding numbers like this as they were doing before:

```
that_function(0x0002 | 0x0004);
```